# Prevent multiple counters to increment or decrement simultaneously

Tags: jquery

I have a simple counter the increment and decrement depends on what operation you choose.

and its working fine.

The problem is when I create multiple counters it simultaneously change or update the value.

Thanks, hope you understand me.

I update the snippet

```js
var $input = $(".counter-percentage input");

$input.val("0.1%");

$(".counter-percentage .operation").click(function() {
  var val = +$input.val().replace("%", "");
  console.log(val);
  if ($(this).hasClass('add'))
    $input.val(Math.round((val + 0.1)*10)/10+'%');
  else if (val >= 0.2)
    $input.val(Math.round((val - 0.1)*10)/10+'%');
});
```

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(247, 204, 131, 0.3);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(247, 204, 131, 0.3);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(247, 204, 131, 0.3);
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li:first-child {
  border: 1px solid rgba(247, 204, 131, 0.3);
  width: 20px;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75px;
}

ul li:last-child {
  width: 20px;
}

ul li input {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li.operation {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="counter-percentage">
  <li class="operation minus">-</li>
  <li>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <input type="text" name="" readonly>
  </li>
  <li class="operation add">+</li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul class="counter-percentage">
  <li class="operation minus">-</li>
  <li>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <input type="text" name="" readonly>
  </li>
  <li class="operation add">+</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I see just one counter and it is being incremented properly. Where are you facing the issue ?

Comment: sorry I forgot, Im adding it now

Answer (score 1):

Inside your click function, replace `$input` with `$(this).siblings().find("input")`

This will look for the input.

I've updated your code a bit.

```
$(".counter-percentage input").val("0.1%");
$(".counter-percentage .operation").click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).siblings().find("input");
  var val = +$input.val().replace("%", "");
  if ($(this).hasClass('add'))
    $(this).siblings().find("input").val(Math.round((val + 0.1)*10)/10+'%');
  else if (val >= 0.2)
    $(this).siblings().find("input").val(Math.round((val - 0.1)*10)/10+'%');
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".counter-percentage input").val("0.1%");


$(".counter-percentage .operation").click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).siblings().find("input");
  var val = +$input.val().replace("%", "");
  if ($(this).hasClass('add'))
    $(this).siblings().find("input").val(Math.round((val + 0.1)*10)/10+'%');
  else if (val >= 0.2)
    $(this).siblings().find("input").val(Math.round((val - 0.1)*10)/10+'%');
});
```

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(247, 204, 131, 0.3);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(247, 204, 131, 0.3);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(247, 204, 131, 0.3);
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li:first-child {
  border: 1px solid rgba(247, 204, 131, 0.3);
  width: 20px;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75px;
}

ul li:last-child {
  width: 20px;
}

ul li input {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li.operation {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="counter-percentage">
  <li class="operation minus">-</li>
  <li>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <input type="text" name="" readonly>
  </li>
  <li class="operation add">+</li>
</ul>

<ul class="counter-percentage">
  <li class="operation minus">-</li>
  <li>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <input type="text" name="" readonly>
  </li>
  <li class="operation add">+</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @MarkGerrylMirandilla No problem. I've updated your code a bit. nothing huge.